# Invalid Syntax with Try and Except

Tags: python, function, dictionary, beautifulsoup, try-catch

So I am trying to webscrape a shoes site.. and two prices show up the original price and previous price.

I am trying to get only the original hence the try and except

Hi can anyone help, i have no idea why i am getting this error or i missed a comma or something in my dictionary ?

My indentions are correct. What could be the problem ?? :(

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
       
s = HTMLSession()
        ​    
r = s.get("https://www.koovs.com/men/footwear/?type=list&sort=price-low&filter_style_fq=18030")
    
r.html.render(sleep=3)        ​
        ​        ​    
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
        
All = soup.find_all('li',class_='imageView')
        ​    
Prods = []
        ​   
for a in All:

  def Price(a):

   try:

    a.find("span", class_= "product_price").next.text

   except:

    a.find("span", class_= "product_price").text

  F = {"Links" : f'https://www.koovs.com{a.find("a")["href"]}',
  "Price" : Price(a)}

  Prods.append(F)
    
Final = pd.DataFrame(Prods)
    
Final.to_excel("Links.xlsx",index = False)
```

Comment: You can't have a `try/except` block in your dictionary definition. I suggest you put it in a function and use that instead.

Comment: hi, i have edited my code and included the function but now i get the final excel file with only the links BUT the Price column is s empty :(

Comment: Now you are declaring function in a for loop. Doesn't sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a return statement to the function, otherwise it will just return None.

```
return a.find("span", class_= "product_price").next.text
```

Also I would declare your function outside of the loop.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def Price(a):

   try:
        return a.find("span", class_= "product_price").next.text
   except:
        return a.find("span", class_= "product_price").text

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get("https://www.koovs.com/men/footwear/?type=list&sort=price-low&filter_style_fq=18030")
r.html.render(sleep=3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")    
All = soup.find_all('li',class_='imageView')

Prods = []
for a in All:
    F = {"Links" : f'https://www.koovs.com{a.find("a")["href"]}',
         "Price" : Price(a)}
    Prods.append(F)
    
Final = pd.DataFrame(Prods)
    
Final.to_excel("Links.xlsx",index = False)
```